# How to fix this error Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: dpkg

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

Comment: Did you run that command? `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened.  Now Synaptic pkg manager is not working.  Maybe I should reinstall it?

Comment: E: The package draftsight needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: I think you need to tell us much more. Which Ubuntu version are you using, when did the package problems start? Did you upgrade to a new Ubuntu version? Also, please edit your question and include the complete output of the terminal commands `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`